# How do I idiomatically implement From<A<T>> for A<U> without conflict?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I have created a generic, monadic type -- call it `A<T>`. I would like to be able to have this type convert safely between `A<T>` to `A<U>` if `U: From<T>`, while still encapsulating it within an `A<_>`, ideally without having to expose or use a `T` directly.

What I would *like* to do, is to implement [`From<A<T>>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) constrained with `U: From<T>`; however the following code does not compile:

```rust
struct A<T>{
    val: T
}

impl<T, U> From<A<T>> for A<U>
    where U: From<T>
{
    fn from(other: A<T>) -> A<U> {
        A{ val: U::from(other.val) }
    }
}
```

The above fails to compile due to the generic implementation `impl<T> From<T> for T` defined in `core`. The full error is:

> ```
> error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::convert::From<A<_>>` for type `A<_>`
>  --> src/lib.rs:5:1
>   |
> 5 | impl<T, U> From<A<T>> for A<U>
>   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   |
>   = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
>           - impl<T> From<T> for T;
> ```

<kbd>[Demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f88434ec00c58e08a73173ee207a071f)</kbd>

The reason for *why* this fails is clear: this definition applies for cases where `T == U`, which would make this `impl From<A<T>> for A<T>` which is the same as `From<T> for T` -- and thus, a conflict. However what is *not clear* is what the idiomatic approach is to overcome this -- since I cannot imagine I am the only one to want to keep a type fully encapsulated.

Is this possible to achieve without needing unstable features like negative trait-bounds or trait-specializations? If not, what is the general, idiomatic approach to support a [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) conversion while still encapsulating the type? Am I stuck implementing a function that behaves exactly like `fn from(...)`, but without implementing the trait?

Comment: I'm sure this question has already been asked somewhere, so I'd be happy if someone were to close this with a link to the appropriate answer. The best I was able to find was other developers experiencing the "conflicting implementation" error for different reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There is no way** to make

```rust
impl<T, U> From<A<T>> for A<U>
    where U: From<T>
```

succeed. (Even if a future version of Rust offers specialization, it would only work here if the built-in `From<T> for T` impl were marked as *allowing* specialization.)

Your choices are:

- Implement the conversion for *concrete* non-equal types — `From<A<Bar>> for A<Foo>`. (I assume this is not desirable for your application, but you seem interested in a broad answer.)
- As you already thought of, “implementing a function that behaves exactly like `fn from(...)`, but without implementing the trait”. I'd write it like:

  ```rust
  impl<T> A<T> {
      fn convert<U>(self) -> A<U> where T: Into<U> {
          A { val: self.val.into() }
      }
  }
  ```

  But note that if your monadic type has a `map()` method, then this is just `.map(Into::into)`.
- Define your own conversion trait, that is not `From`.

  There's probably no reason to do this in your case, unless you have other types similar to `A`, but considered broadly, this is actually fairly common; many libraries define `IntoFoo` trait(s), for various reasons.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful answer! Sadly this is pretty much as I expected it would be; I guess i was just hoping there was an actual approved way to accomplish this